# Buscar último elemento de un .each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla sencilla de la siguiente forma

`tbody > tr > td`

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Código 1</td>
        <td>Nombre 1</td>
        <td>Precio 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Código 2</td>
        <td>Nombre 2</td>
        <td>Precio 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Estoy tratando de obtener el último elemento de un `.each` con jquery. Por ejemplo, cuando la variable `code` obtenga el codigo 2, la variable `codex` tiene que contener el código 1.

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera, pero en vez de traerme sólo la primera columna del td, me trae todas

```js
 $(function () {
        $('table tr > td:nth-child(1), table tr > th:nth-child(1)').each(function (index) {
            var code = $(this).text();
            var codex = $(this).parent().prev().text();
           console.log("var code contiene " + code + " - var codex contiene " + codex);
        });
    });
```

```
console.log muestra lo siguiente:

var code contiene Código 2 - var codex contiene Código 1 Nombre 1 precio 1 -
```

Comment: Por que no `$('table tr > td:last-child')`?

Comment: Cierto, pero lo que necesito es que codex solo muestre first-child tambien, y no lo hace

Comment: `var codex = $(this).parent().first('td')` will work!

Comment: El problema está en que al usar ".parent()" estás seleccionando la fila (TR) de la celda actual. Con ".prev()" seleccionar la fila anterior y ".text()" devuelve todas las celdas. 
Si quieres recuperar la primera celda (<td>Código 1</td>) de la fila anterior, prueba a elegir solo el primer hijo:
 $(this) -> Elemento (TD)
.parent() -> Padre (TR)
.prev() -> padre previo (TR)
.first('td') -> primer hijo (TD)
.text(); -> contenido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si he entendido bien necesitas:

1. El valor del primer `td` de la última fila de la tabla
2. El valor del primer `td` de la penúltima fila de la tabla

Para eso no necesitas recorrer toda la tabla, lo cual podría tener un impacto negativo en el rendimiento si se tratase de una tabla grande. Puedes valerte de selectores específicos para obtener ambos valores.

Aquí usamos `table tr:last td:first-child` para obtener el valor requerido en (1)  y luego usamos `prev()` seguido de `find("td:first-child")` para obtener el valor requerido en (2).

```js
$(function() {
  var code = $("table tr:last td:first-child").text();
  var codex = $("table tr:last").prev().find("td:first-child").text();
  console.log(`var code contiene ${code} y var codex contiene ${codex}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Código 1</td>
      <td>Nombre 1</td>
      <td>Precio 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Código 2</td>
      <td>Nombre 2</td>
      <td>Precio 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```